# "Query Completed with an Empty Output" How to get it to put a zero when there are no results instead

Tags: google-sheets, sum, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

My query is yielding an error

> `#N/A` Query Completed with an Empty Output.

```
=sum((query(importrange("mysheet","CR"),"select Col7 where Col1 ='"&A4&"' and Col2 ='"&B4&"' and Col13!='Cancelled' and Col13!='Rejected' ",0)))
```

The function is working properly when data exists in the referenced sheet. The issue is as I drag it down some of the column references don't exist in the CR data set. How do I get a zero to populate instead of the error?

Answer (score 6):

you need to use `IFERROR` like this which will result in 0 if an error happens:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("mysheet","CR"), 
 "select Col7 
  where Col1 ='"&A4&"' 
    and Col2 ='"&B4&"' 
    and Col13!='Cancelled' 
    and Col13!='Rejected' ", 0)))
```